# Point covariance for a given data set

Tags: statistics, covariance

In the paper, "Data analysis recipes: Fitting a model to data" (Hogg, Bovy, Lang), individual data point variances are found and used for subsequent statistical analysis. The data and corresponding variances are shown in the image below.
[image]

The paper cites that the full uncertainty covariance matrix for each data point is given by

[image]

How is this convariance matrix for each point found?

Answer (score 1):

This is just the definition of the [covariance matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariance_matrix#Definition). Each element along the diagonal is the variance of each random variable. The off-diagonal elements are the covariances, in terms of $\rho_{xy}$ the [correlation of coefficient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pearson_correlation_coefficient#For_a_population).